# Displaying a Sparse matrix from a linked list which has stored only non zeros element

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a sparse matrix that the user has input and a linked list which stores only non-zero elements and ignore the all zeros. Now, My aim is from this linked list, try to get all the elements from the sparse matrix including the zeros and non-zeros element and display it.Someone show me a way of light please or some instructions or ideas

> Sparse Matrix where user inputs all elements(Zeros & Non-Zeros )

```
int row;
int column;
int count=0;
int sparseMatrix[10][10];
cout<<"Enter Number of Rows: ";
cin>>row;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Enter Number of Column: ";
cin>>column;
cout<<endl;
int i,j;
cout<<"Enter Elements in the Matrix: ";
for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        cin>> sparseMatrix[i][j];
        if (sparseMatrix[i][j]==0)
            count++;
    }
}
```

> Link List which reads only Non-zero elements from the Sparse matrix and display them

```
void PrintList(struct node* start)

{
struct node *temp, *r, *s;
temp = r = s = start;

cout<<"row_position:";
while(temp != NULL)
{

    cout<<temp->rowposition;
    temp = temp->next;
}
cout<<endl;
printf("column_postion: ");
while(r != NULL)
{
    cout<<r->columnposition;
    r = r->next;
}
cout<<endl;
printf("Value: ");
while(s != NULL)
{
    cout<<s->value;
    s = s->next;
}
    cout<<endl;
}
```

> Creation of the link list nodes

```
    struct node {
    int value;
    int rowposition;
    int columnposition;
        struct node *next;
    };
void createNewNode (struct node** start, int NonZeroElement, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) // functions with parameter
{
    struct node *temp, *r;
    temp = *start;
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        temp=(struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node)); // creates a new node dynamically
        temp -> value= NonZeroElement;
        temp -> rowposition = rowIndex;
        temp -> columnposition = columnIndex;
        temp -> next=NULL;
        *start = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;

        // Create new node dynamically
        r = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
        r->value = NonZeroElement;
        r->rowposition = rowIndex;
        r->columnposition = columnIndex;
        r->next = NULL;
        temp->next = r;
    }
}
```

My aim is to Display This Matrix as shown in this figure :
[This is how the Matrix Should be displayed.My Aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkXYq.png)
this is My output so far in the picture:

[My Current Output of this code so far picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9JV1.png)

Comment: Have you tried writing anything to display your matrix? StackOverflow will not write your code for you. Please show your (relevant) efforts and explain exactly what is keeping you from solving this yourself.

Comment: Sir I don't have the idea on how to get the zeros back from my link list which I have created.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to consider the structure of your function call PrintList or your sparse Matrix data structure itself. Somewhere, either in the data structure or in the printList method should be the desired row by column structure of the sparse matrix. Consider the problem of having a 4x4 matrix with all zeroes except one value at [1,2]. The print method would not know that you want a 4x4 matrix at all with the exception of a single value at [1,2] unless either the print method received an input for number of rows and colums, or the data structure itself retained those values. This should allow for the function call to be more self-supportive and not relying on code in your main body to dictate that for you. 
On another note, since you are going to have to print row x column values anyways there is little overhead in creating a nested for loop for rows and columns and checking whether or not the current linked list node row and column values are indeed the ones in the control variables for the nested loop structure. If not, you could print zero and when you get to the end of the inner for loop, you could print a new line to handle your code.
Of course, you could just have a linked list of values and you could use that to set the dimensionality of your matrix. In the example I gave, you would end up with 2 x 3 matrix printed out instead of maybe a desired 4 x 4 since the maximum row and column value were [1,2]. This would probably lead to undesired results, however, as matrix operations typically require very specific dimensionalities and that loss of information could give you bad results. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm more confused I must say after reading this. Can you be more specific of what method can I applied to convert the non-zero linked list into zeros and non zeros in the sparse matrix and display it?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to provide more ways that you could implement your method. Is your data structure supposed to retain some idea of its size? In my example if you had one element at [1,2], say 5 then the resulting matrix could be any number of matrices like [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]] or [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0]] or even [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5]] all of which would have the same sparse matrix represenation but would give you different outputs. What is the desired output?